# Linux [Hardware Error] message from kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, syslog, opensuse, hardware

Since yesterday I get the following message every few minutes:

```
Message from syslogd@hostname at Nov 23 12:31:17 ...  kernel:[8024326.816370] [Hardware Error]: MC4_STATUS: Corrected error, other errors lost: yes, CPU context corrupt: no, CECC Error

Message from syslogd@hostname at Nov 23 12:31:17 ...  kernel:[8024326.838430] [Hardware Error]: Northbridge Error, node 0: DRAM ECC error detected on the NB.

Message from syslogd@hostname at Nov 23 12:31:17 ...  kernel:[8024326.855732] [Hardware Error]: Transaction: RD (MEM), no timeout, Cache Level: L3/GEN, Participating Processor: RES
```

Does anybody know what to do about it?

I am running:

```
openSUSE 11.4 "Celadon"
Linux 2.6.37.6-0.7-default #1 SMP 2011-07-21 02:17:24 +0200
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a faulty memory. Try `memtest86` overnight and see if it catches the errors. Of course that program is not bulletproof but usually can give good hints.